# can I make the output array with the condition

Tags: php, arrays

Сreate a big array, then it sort, and then I should get for example the first n elements of a sorted array.

Create array:

```
foreach ($array_RESPONSEdata as $key => $row) {
 $new_created_time[$key] = $row['DATE_PIC'];
 $new_thumbnail[$key] = $row['LINK_PIC'];
 $new_tags_name [$key] = $row['TAG_PIC'];
}
```

At the output of the get array, like this:

```
Array (
[0] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1376566005 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage3.s3.amazonaws.com/90ebfcc2059d11e381c522000a9e035f_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => test )
[1] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1376222415 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage9.s3.amazonaws.com/957a78a4027d11e3a72522000a1fb586_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => test )
[2] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1374685904 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage2.s3.amazonaws.com/1dbe356ef48411e2931722000a1fc67c_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => test )
[3] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1373909177 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage0.s3.amazonaws.com/0fd9b22adce711e2a7ab22000a1f97eb_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => test )
[4] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1372089573 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage0.s3.amazonaws.com/0fd9b22adce711e2a7ab22000a1f97eb_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => test )
[5] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1371468982 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage0.s3.amazonaws.com/0fd9b22adce711e2a7ab22000a1f97eb_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => test )
)
```

Next, sort an array by key DATE_PIC:

```
array_multisort($new_created_time, SORT_DESC, $array_RESPONSEdata);
```

Get an array with reverse the sort.

---

Question: How now as after sorting, the first three lines of output?

Comment: `How now after sorting bring suppose the first three lines?` -- could you clarify?

Comment: `array_slice($array_RESPONSEdata, 0, 3)`?

Comment: @kojiro Oooo cool! Didn't know about array_slice :) thank you very much. We had to respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't need to separate the array to begin with, this would save some memory if it fits into your application:

```
<?php

    // Will sort using 'DATE_PIC' as index.
    array_multisort( $array_RESPONSEdata, SORT_ASC );

    // We'll define a buffer, so PHP doesn't need to echo every time (list-style).
    $buffer = array();

    /**
     * You mentioned 'get the first n elements', to specify how many
     * rows you want to get, you can specify the max count in a for loop
     * array_multisort reassigns numeric index keys in order after sorting.
     *
     * e.g. If we want 5 records to count:
     * $max = 5;
     *
     * If you want all that is returned you can do this:
     * $max = count( $array_RESPONSEdata );
     */
    $max = 5;

    for( $n = 0; $n < $max; $n++ )
    {
        $buffer[] = '<ul>';
        $buffer[] = '<li>' . $array_RESPONSEdata[$n]['TAG_PIC'] . '</li>';
        $buffer[] = '<li>' . $array_RESPONSEdata[$n]['DATE_PIC'] . '</li>';
        $buffer[] = '<li><img src="' . $array_RESPONSEdata[$n]['LINK_PIC'] . '" alt="' . $array_RESPONSEdata[$n]['TAG_PIC'] . '"/>';
        $buffer[] = '</ul>';
    }

    // And now the output magic (Not really):
    echo implode( "\r\n", $buffer );
?>
```

Of course, structure your HTML as needed, that was only for example. By the way, for reference I use `"\r\n"` to splice my buffer together because the source prints on separate lines, making it easy to see what's going on in the source for html/css adjustments.

Comment: Not a problem at all, glad it was what you were looking for.